# creating popup message

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to show a popup window for few seconds to greet users on their desktop. 
it should be non-interactive.i want to do this in c# ,winform or wpf.
For example, 
After user logged in, For every 3 hours , “Hello” message  Should be shown for a second, then auto hide.
can anyone give some ideas.
thanks

Comment: Don't you think the users will be annoyed if it is recurring?

Answer (score 3):

In WPF:

Use [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) control to display your "Hello".

In the application, to set up recurring popup display and close, set up an instance of [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Create a form to display whatever message you want, size it however you feel.  But a timer on it for 3 seconds that will  do form.close() when the timer expires.

when your app loads, have it display the form.